# .htaccess rewrite a url to a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't think this is possible, however I would like to ask the community to see if it is.

I have a blog on a subdomain `blog.domain.com` due to a revamp of the site we are having to use the blog on a trailing domain `domain.com/blog` this isnt ideal as all our old post permalinks point to the subdomain.

I was therefore wondering if there is a way to use the `.htaccess` to rewrite `domain.com/blog -> blog.domain.com`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to redirect all the traffic from `blog.domain.com` to `domain.com/blog`. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(blog)\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%2/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.